# Is the limit function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

> Is this function continuous or not? $$y\ =\ \lim _{a\to +\infty }\bigg[\frac{\ln \left(1+e^{\alpha \cdot x}\right)}{\ln \left(1+e^{\alpha }\right)}\bigg]$$

I computed that limit of function as $a\to+\infty$ is $x$. How I proceed from here for proving the **continuous** part?

Comment: What do you know about the quotient of continuous functions?

Comment: It is continuous

Comment: Oh I guess I chose the wrong way for proving?

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is continuous

Comment: Right, so I don't understand what the problem is.  If you are asking about the quotient, as a function of $\alpha$ for fixed $x$, then it's continuous.  If you're asking about the limit, as a function of $x$, then of course, $f(x)=x$ is continuous.

Comment: @saulspatz : How does that help? Certainly the quotient is continuous as a function of either $\alpha$ or $x,$ but the question is about the limit as $\alpha\to+\infty$ as a function of $x. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Well, I wasn't sure what he was asking about, as I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating the limit gives
$$y = \lim _{a\to +\infty }\frac{\ln \left(1+e^{a \cdot x}\right)}{\ln \left(1+e^{a }\right)} = \lim_{a\to+\infty}\frac{xe^{ax}(1+e^a)}{e^a(1+e^{ax})} = x$$
and $y=x$ is continuous.